# How to configure SBT for a non custom sources directory

Tags: sbt

I succeeded in configuring SBT to look for sources outside its default directory structure.

```
val absoluteDir = "/home/.../[fooProjectBaseDirectory]/"
unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile += new File(absoluteDir + "jvm/src")
unmanagedSourceDirectories in Test += new File(absoluteDir + "jvm/test/src")
```

In the real world I want to achieve the same by using a relative directory.

I tried:

```
sourceDirectory in Compile := baseDirectory.value / "jvm" / "src"
sourceDirectory in Test := baseDirectory.value / "jvm" / "test" / "src"
```

but sbt seems to append the **scala-2.12**, **scala** or **java** directories to my path, causing the search to fail.

> sbt:foo> **inspect compile:unmanagedSourceDirectories**
>   [info]
>   Setting: scala.collection.Seq[java.io.File] =
>   List(/home/.../[fooProjectBaseDirectory]/jvm/src/**scala-2.12**,
>   /home/.../[fooProjectBaseDirectory]/jvm/src/**scala**,
>   /home/.../[fooProjectBaseDirectory]/jvm/src/**java**)

Any hint?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. Both are working:

```
unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile += baseDirectory.value / "jvm" / "src"
unmanagedSourceDirectories in Test += baseDirectory.value / "jvm" / "test" / "src"
```

or

```
Compile / unmanagedSourceDirectories += baseDirectory.value / "jvm" / "src"
Test / unmanagedSourceDirectories += baseDirectory.value / "jvm" / "test" / "src"
```